# How to switch template for search results without using views and display modes?

Tags: views, theming, search

I want to show my Drupal 10 Solr search results in either grid view or list view.
I set this up using Views and Display Modes, and I have icons on the page which simply link to the URLs of the different display modes.

However I am using Facets with my search, and using the above approach requires setting up duplicate Facet Blocks for each display mode. This is inefficient and difficult to maintain.

Is there a more efficient way of re-rendering the same page but with a different set of templates for displaying the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for this limitation of Facets applying to only one display in one view, discussed here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/issues/2826650

The workaround consists of altering the search query event and overriding the checkbox widget for the facet blocks.